# When should I use " 's "

Tags: possessives

If I want to describe a development process of some company called "The Company", should I use "'s" at the end of the company name(The Company)?

What are the cases when I shouldn't use " 's " at the end?

The Company's Development Process

Is this the correct form of saying this?

Thanks!

Comment: "The Company" is a very unusual company name, because they don't usually have "The" in the name. It could actually change the answer. It would normally be a name like *Acme,* and it would be quite normal to talk of "Acme's Development Process" or "The Acme Development Process" (where *The* is the definite article for *Process*).

Comment: Thank you Andrew. So as I got it from your answer, I can use both variants(correct if I'm wrong please): 1) COMPANYTECH's Development Process 2) The COMPANYTECH Development process